# Comma separated column ids should show values or text(with function or query)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this

Foreign table:

```
select * from table1
ID......NameIds
-------------------
1 ......1, 2 (its comma separated values)
```

Primary table(table2)

```
ID  Name
-------------------
1      Cleo  
2      Smith
```

I want to show table 1 as like (I require SQL function or query for it)

```
ID......NameIds
-------------------
1........Cleo, smith (show text/Name instead of values)
```

Comment: SQL isn't designed for comma separated values, you'll only get lots of problems if you keep storing data like that.

Comment: You should fix your data structure, and use a junction table (one row per `id` and `nameId`).  Don't store lists in strings.  Don't store numbers as strings.

Answer (score 1):

As per stated in comments - you should really rethink your table design, but it was interesting enough to try and write a query for that:

```
SELECT T1.ID, NameID, Name
INTO #Temporary
FROM #Table1 AS T1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT CAST(('<X>' + REPLACE(T1.NameIDs, ',', '</X><X>') + '</X>') AS XML)
    ) AS X(XmlData)
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT NameID.value('.', 'INT')
    FROM XmlData.nodes('X') AS T(NameID)
    ) AS T(NameID)
INNER JOIN #Table2 AS T2
    ON T2.ID = T.NameID

SELECT ID, STUFF(T.Names, 1, 1, '') AS Names
FROM #Table1 AS T1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT ',' + Name
    FROM #Temporary AS T
    WHERE T.ID = T1.ID
    ORDER BY T.NameID
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ) AS T(Names)
```

**Result:**

```
ID  Names
--------------
1   Cleo,Smith
```

What it does, it splits your comma seperated list into rows, joins them on NameIDs and then concatenates them again. Guess how efficient is that?
It's probably not the most best way to do that, but it works.